# Function Number of paid invoices prior to the creation date of a new invoice of a customer

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I´m trying to run a function even though im not quite sure if this is the correct answer. Im new to Rstudio and im trying to get count of Number of paid invoices prior to the creation date of a new invoice of each customer and another column of Number of invoices which were paid late
prior to the creation date of a new invoice of each customer
My data:

```
set.seed(123)

names<- rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 16)
id<- seq(1,32)
daysp<- runif(1:32,1,32)
startdate <-c("20-02-2018","01-03-2018","13-03-2018","20-03-2018","28-03-2018","05-04-2018","10-04-2018","13-04-2018",
        "16-04-2018","19-04-2018","04-05-2018","14-05-2018","23-05-2018","04-06-2018","12-06-2018","19-06-2018",
        "26-04-2018","02-05-2018","07-05-2018","07-05-2018","07-05-2018","14-05-2018","29-05-2018","12-06-2018",
        "12-06-2018","18-06-2018","11-07-2018","11-07-2018","17-07-2018","30-07-2018","03-08-2018","07-08-2018")
startdate<-as.Date(startdate,"%d-%m-%Y" )
paydate<- startdate + daysp
class <- c("Payed", "Payed","Payed", "Delayed","Payed", "Delayed","Delayed", "Delayed","Payed", "Delayed",
       "Payed", "Delayed","Payed", "Delayed","Payed", "Delayed","Payed", "Delayed","Payed", "Delayed",
       "Payed", "Delayed","Payed", "Delayed","Payed", "Delayed","Delayed", "Delayed","Payed", "Delayed",
       "Payed", "Delayed")
df<-data.frame(names,id,daysp,startdate,paydate,class)
```

My expected result looks like this:

```
nopip<-c(0,0,1,1,3,3,4,4,4,5,7,10,10,12,12,14,0,0,2,2,2,2,3,6,6,6,9,9,10,12,13,14)
nopip_delayed<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,3,5,5,6,6,6,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8)
```

like this Dataframe

```
df<-cbind(df,nopip,nopip_delayed)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this, but here is one using base R which is good to understand for building a foundation to expand.

This uses `lapply` to step through the `data.frame` and check if the names match that row along with the pay date being prior to the start date.

```
df$nopip2 <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(x) sum(df$names == df$names[x] & df$paydate < df$startdate[x]))
```

This does the same sequence as the previous function, but adds an additional check if the class was delayed.

```
df$nopip_delayed2 <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(x) sum(df$names == df$names[x] & df$paydate < df$startdate[x] & df$class == 'Delayed'))
```

Confirming calculated results are same as desired output

```
> setequal(df$nopip, df$nopip2)
[1] TRUE
> setequal(df$nopip_delayed, df$nopip_delayed2)
[1] TRUE
```

Added example to `sum` the `daysp` with respective `nopip`

```
df$nopip_daysp <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(x) sum((df$names == df$names[x] & df$paydate < df$startdate[x]) * df$daysp))
```

As a side note iterating through a `data.frame` is an expensive option if the number of rows is large.  However, using the steps above will be an easy transition if that time arises.

Comment: Thanks for the answer yesterday. It was very helpful for the model im preparing. I have been trying to use lapply to sum for example the daysp of each id with by their respectives nopip. If it's not too much trouble could you give me some advice or a way to do it?

Comment: @FenicoAlarcon I'll update the answer with an example, but it would take the value you want to `sum` and multiply it by the same logic above where `TRUE` evaluates to 1 and `FALSE` evaluates to 0.  This will `sum` only values where the logic is `TRUE`.